# Время умножения матриц различных размеров

Tags: c++, gcc, матрицы

Добрый день,

есть класс `Matrix` (репрезентирует матрицу):

```
class Matrix {
private:
    long long **table;
    int n; // rows
    int m; // columns
public:
    /* конструкторы, деструкторы и прочее */ 
    void multiply(Matrix &A, Matrix &B){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < A.m; k++)
                    table[i][j] += A.table[i][k] * B.table[k][j]; // далее операция Mul
    }
};
```

Так вот балуясь с этим классом, а именно тестируя, как быстро умножаются 2 матрицы, столкнулся со следующей ситуацией:

предположим, проводим мы 3 умножения:

```
[5'000'000*5]*[5*5] = [5'000'000*5] // 5'000'000*5*5 операций Mul
[5*5'000'000]*[5'000'000*5] = [5*5] // 5*5*5'000'000 операций Mul
[500*500]*[500*500] = [500*500] // 500*500*500 операций Mul
```

Результаты таковы, что среднее время выполнения у всех троих различается, хотя и количество Mul казалось бы одинаковое. Самый лучший результат у первого умножения (3 сек), потом у второго (4.3 сек), затем у третьего (4.5 сек).

Что по вашему является причиной различий?

P.S. Код тестирован с различными оптимизациями:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.P.S Какое обращение выполнится быстрее `a[10]` или же `a[1000]`?

P.P.P.S Заметьте, я не собираюсь оптимизировать этот код или же улучшать его как-либо, я хочу всего лишь разобраться в причине такого поведения.

Comment: У вас же не только операции умножения тут, а ещё и сложения. А различее результато может быть вызвано попаданием каких-то данных в кеш например или выпадением из кеша. И конечно лучше тестировать с оптимизацией наверное.

Comment: с оптимизацие тоже тестировал, тоже самое, наверное стоит добавить это в шапку

Comment: Может быть вам стоит воспользоваться профилировщиком, он наверника покажет какие операции тратят больше всего времени.

Comment: `a[10] или же a[1000]` - одинаково. Но при условии, что и оно одинаково закешировано

Comment: @KoVadim, что вы имеете в  виду под закешировано?

Comment: у процессора есть кеш. Если данные попали в кеш, они достаются очень быстро, если нет - то часто, на порядок медленее. Так как расстояние между 10 и 1000 вполне может быть таким, что данные не попадают в кеш, то доступ к одному может оказаться сильно быстрее, чем к другому. Но это только потому, что к примеру, перед этим читались данные по нулевому адресу.

Comment: То есть в первом случае в наш кэш вполне может попасть вся вторая матрица, и тогда обращение к ней будет куда уж быстрее, чем к обычной памяти ?

Comment: может быть. Это все нужно исследовать профайлерами

Comment: дело конечно в кеше, в последних двух примерах т.к. внутренние циклы идут по столбцам, то нарушается локальность данных... и более честным и показательным примером было бы сравнить `[5M*5]*[5*5]` и `[5*5]*[5*5M]`

Comment: я не понимаю ваш код потому что в результате произведений  матрицы A и B   должна быть матрица  размером int size == A.n *B.m, а если  (this -> n * this->m ) < size? Ну это еще легко проверить и исполнить, если  ваш класс хранит указатель, а для указателей на указатели  придется сравнить this->n  >= A.n? && this ->m >= B.m?... И  разные данные могут усложнять или  упростить расчеты, по этому поводу

Comment: по вашему коду B.m == A.m,  тогда делайте размеры статическими

Comment: Я не код править хочу, а всего лишь причину такого поведения :)

Comment: По поводу причины я выше высказал свое мнение, но  это не ответ,  а предположение

Answer (score 0):

Тут верно про кеш процессора пишут. Чтоб быстрее умножать, надо матрицу B разместить в памяти в транспонированном виде и умножать "строка на строку", причем делать это "пачками", т. е. берем 1000 строк из A матрицы и 1000 строк из B (строки, которые были столбцами) и перемножаем, таким образом на 1000*1000 операция числа не будут "вымываться" из кеша. Потом берем следующие 1000 строк из B и перемножаем и так далее пока не перемножим все из A на B.
Число 1000 подбирается из размера кеша процессора и размера матриц.

При записи результата в table будет таже проблема, возможно дешевле будет все писать линейно в массив в виде (index, sum), где index это настоящий индекс ячейки в table, а потом отсортировать table. Но тут не уверен.